# Error establishing a database connection in wordpress xampp

Tags: wordpress

I am new to wordpress. I have started website  with wordpress. yesterday night when I was working, site on localhost, xampp running smoothly. today, as I started xampp, this error was showing and I am searching for solution.
please help me if some one know it.

Thanks in advance.

[image: website error page]

[image: database error page]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your phpMyadmin is not connected. Please connect first.

Comment: xampp is running

Comment: Share a screenshot of pypmyadmin - with your database

Comment: thanks Ravi,
actually port mismatching problem is there so it is showing error.
I matched port and its done.